# throughout the United States

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say: "sell/send/distribute throughout the United States."? The idea is that the person/firm sends/sells/distributes something to every city in the United States. I really want to use 'throughout' and I'm not sure which verb is suitable in that case.

Comment: You have the correct idea. This person sells products throughout the United States.

Comment: Can I use the other verbs as well? Or 'to sell' is the only option here?

Comment: You can use almost any verb that refers to an activity which can occur in multiple places.  *They sang throughout the US.*  Are you looking for synonyms for **sell**?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, I'm not looking for a synonym of "sell." I wasn't sure if all verbs (send/distribute) could be used with "throughout the United States." If it sounds natural to say, e.g. "we distribute throughout the United States". Sometimes you can use a verb in a sentence, but then you realized nobody speaks/writes like that.

Answer (score 1):

***Throughout the United States*** means *everywhere in the United States*. It works with any verb that might reasonably be used with that meaning. There are no special requirements for verbs to work with *throughout*.